# Send/Receive AT commands to GSM modem in python

Tags: python, linux, at-command, ussd

I want to write a simple code in python to send USSD codes to a GSM modem (D-link DWM-157) and receive their results and store them in variables. I can connect to the modem with minicom and also miniterm.py. But the problem is that they need a terminal to send/receive AT commands to the modem. I don't want an extra terminal. I also use the following code to send a simple AT command but when I run the code nothing happens:

```
import serial, time

def serial_def():
    ser = serial.Serial()
    ser.port = "/dev/ttyUSB2"
    ser.baudrate = 115200
    ser.bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS #number of bits per bytes
    ser.parity = serial.PARITY_NONE #set parity check: no parity
    ser.stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE #number of stop bits
    ser.timeout = 2              #timeout block read
    ser.xonxoff = False     #disable software flow control
    ser.rtscts = False     #disable hardware (RTS/CTS) flow control
    ser.dsrdtr = False       #disable hardware (DSR/DTR) flow control
    ser.writeTimeout = 2
    ser.open()

    if ser.isOpen():
         print(ser.name + ' is open...')

    ser.write("AT"+"\r\n")
    time.sleep(1)
    out=''
    while True:
        out += ser.read(1)
        print (out)        

    ser.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    serial_def()
```

When I run the code I only see the following:

```
/dev/ttyUSB2 is open...
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You will never leave the `while` loop.

Comment: I modified the code and put the print inside while loop (and also edited in the question). But now I get empty line. I mean out is empty!!

Comment: Your `AT` command isn't complete, read about [Serial Programming/Modems and AT Commands](https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Serial_Programming/Modems_and_AT_Commands)

Comment: Thank you guys. My problem was the wrong serial port! I changed the port to /dev/ttyUSB1 and now it is working. But the thing which confuses me is that I use /dev/ttyUSB2 in smstools3 but here I have to use /dev/ttyUSB1!!!

Comment: `ser.write("AT"+"\r\n")` - AT commands end with `\r`, not `\r\n`. And instead of `sleep(1)` you should call `tcdrain(fd)` to ensure the write completes. Also see Mike Sweet's [Serial Programming Guide for POSIX Operating Systems](https://www.cmrr.umn.edu/~strupp/serial.html#modem).